# CKEditor Multi-Site Configuration Problem

Tags: multisite, wysiwyg, drupal-multi-site

After updating to 4.7.23 from 4.7.20, I can now use the CKeditor Configuration and the changes are saved based on the changes made at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19303, but the wysiwyg doesn't show up. The Drupal log error message reports "page not found" and that it is looking for

`http://staging.focusdc.org/sites/focus/sites/focusdc.org/modules/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js`

when I believe it should be looking for

`http://staging.focusdc.org/sites/focusdc.org/modules/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js`

I'm not sure how to go about changing this.  Everything else seems to be working correctly as my Resource URL's and Upload Directories look correct.

Thanks in advance

**8/15**

After some further sleuthing I discovered my production site running 4.7.20 reports:
[civicrm.root]  https://focusdc.org/sites/focusdc.org/modules/civicrm/

whilte my staging server running 4.7.23 reports:
[civicrm.root] http://staging.focusdc.org/sites/focus/sites/focusdc.org/modules/civicrm/

They have identical civicrm.settings.php outside of the one having SSL and one referencing "staging".

Did the $civicrm_root settings change in civicrm.settings.php between 4.7.20 and 4.7.23? Any other thoughts?

Comment: To further clarify, I previously was able to get the wysiwyg working (although without the configuration) in 4.7.20 by applying the patch here. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9458/files

Comment: Can you re-check your resource URL setting and clear all caches?

Comment: Thanks for the help Coleman.  I've tried all possible combinations I could think of using absolute URLs and URL variables and nothing works.  Still redirecting to the wrong subdirectories. The extra "/sites/focus" seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jon G, for steering me in the right direction and hopefully this might help someone down the line.

I probably wasn't particularly clear in my description in that I run a Drupal multisite but CiviCRM is still running under it's original single site (although this is bringing me a step closer to having all the sites run CiviCRM especially for webform integration).

Accordingly, I was still hosting CiviCRM in the 'subsite'/modules directory. When I moved the module into the /all/modules and changed the $civicrm_root any inconsistencies in the Directories and URL Resources corrected themselves.

Now the CKEditor Configuration works!

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as "Accepted"; this will help future folks.  Thanks for reporting back!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by [defining the CIVICRM_CMSDIR constant](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19881/how-can-i-fix-civicrm-root-variable-on-an-addon-domain/19958#19958).  Since you're using multi-site, you'll need to define that on a per-site basis.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the reply.  I've tried all angles of implementing the CIVICRM_CMSDIR constant and it does help correct the cms directory root, which will probably alleviate some pain in the future. However, it doesn't fix the extra "/sites/focus" when ckeditor is loading.

Comment: Do you have a symlink somewhere in your $civicrm_root?

Comment: I do have a symlink from the /var/lib/mysql to the location of mysql databases.  Could that cause it?