# How can I fix [civicrm.root] variable on an addon domain?

Tags: wordpress, civimail, civicrm.settings.php, resource-urls

I believe `[civicrm.root]` is being computed incorrectly. Entering the absolute URLs in `Settings > Resource URLs` has been sufficient to fix most problems, but some problems persist.

For example, when i encounter an error like  crm.ckeditor.js  getting an error, the console tells me it can't find it at `https://mysite.org/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js.`

You'll notice that `mysite.org` is repeated.

I'm running (CiviCRM 4.7.22) on an "Addon Domain" on my host. When you manage files for your addon domains, they show up as a folder on in your file manager. So my Civi files are installed at:

- `/home/username/public_html/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/`

I assume that when Civi is computing the `[civicrm.root]` variable, it just assumes it can replace `/home/username/public_html` with the base url defined by `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL`, which would explain why I'm getting this `https://mysite.org/mysite.org/wp-content...`.

So how do I fix this permanently? Clearly using absolute URLs in `Settings > Resource URLs` isn't sufficient for every case. To clarify the values frrom `settings.civicrm.php`:

- `define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://mysite.org/');`
- `$civicrm_root = '/home/user/public_html/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';`

Comment: [civicrm_root] is calculated from `$civicrm_root`, which is defined in `civicrm.settings.php`.  You should edit `civicrm.settings.php` to use CKEditor.  As to your original question - 90% of what's posted here is a red herring.  Could you please rewrite the question to be reflective of what you've found regarding the calculation issue?

Comment: Rewrote for clarity. I know that `[civicrm.root]` is defined in `civicrm.settings.php` but I need to know _what_ to change so that my URLs are calculated correctly.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the values of `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` and also of `$civicrm_root`?  I'm having a hard time visualizing the values from the outputs.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for sticking with me :). I think the issue is stemming from the fact that the files are in a directory called `mysite.org`.

Comment: Hmm - I think you might be hitting the WordPress CiviCRM symlink issue.  Is there a symlink in your file path?  Particularly to mysite.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr: Uncomment and fill in the** `define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR', '/path/to/install/root/');` in `civicrm.settings.php`.

I traced through the functions that go toward building the URL for loadins `crm.ckeditor.js`.  It seems there's a problem with the logic of the WordPress [cmsRootPath](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/c9a664cbd3d1c5d30490e57696533c16b5ef48a0/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L483) function.

I can't tell you what the specific issue you're having that's causing that function to fail; I know it struggles with symlinks, and I'd guess there's other edge cases as well.

If I understand [this line of code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/c9a664cbd3d1c5d30490e57696533c16b5ef48a0/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L490) correctly, in addition to `$civicrm_root`, there's also a lesser-known cousin `CIVICRM_CMSDIR`, which is actually the relevant data here.  In my 4.7.22 WordPress instance's `civicrm.settings.php`, that constant is present but commented out.

See also: [CRM-18221](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18221) for what appears to be a similar issue on earlier versions of Civi 4.7.

Comment: Uncommenting the `global $civicrm_setting` and defining `CIVICRM_CMSDIR` seems to have fixed the URL Variable calculation errors as evidenced . This issue has been bugging me for a long time. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that I have the same problem: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20888/wysiwyg-editor-not-present-with-wordpress. But defining CIVICRM_CSDIR only makes matters worse (duplicating more of [civicrm.root]. I have two servers one live in mysite.org and the other test.mysite.org with all the files in subdirectory test of the live site. I have a quick fix by replacing (by trial and error) [civicrm.root] in the call to CKEditor with wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm. Can you be more specific on what you changed?